# Apache web server configuration gives 404 error message

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

Mates,
I've been looking arround but still couldn't find the solution.

I have this on `apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /home/pablo/htdocs/elementalguru/cuentas/idpetecuador.com/www/system/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This on `000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    # ServerName localhost

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/pablo/htdocs

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/pablo/htdocs/elementalguru/cuentas/idpetecuador.com/www/system/public"
    ServerName eguru.idpet.sys
</VirtualHost>
```

And the `.htaccess` file on public folder is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But still when I try to access a url like

```
http://eguru.idpet.sys/clinicas
```

Which is stated in hosts file.

I get a 404 error message.

Any idea why?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your apache log what is your apache trying to serve when you make that request.

Comment: If you put a file, say, test.html in `/home/pablo/htdocs/elementalguru/cuentas/idpetecuador.com/www/system/public`, does it get served when you go to http://localhost/test.html?

Comment: Yes, it does get served

Comment: Then you should access your project by using url: http://localhost/ instead of the very long one you posted. The `DocumentRoot` in your apache config already told that when a user access http://localhost/, apache should go look at the files in `/home/pablo/htdocs/elementalguru/cuentas/idpetecuador.com/www/system/public` automatically, so you don't need to include all those subfolders in your url.

Comment: I had copied the wrong url.
I was trying to access the site with the url that's now on the question.
I've created a virtual host that points to /home/pablo/htdocs/elementalguru/cuentas/idpetecuador.com/www/system/public.
The thing is that when I go to http://eguru.idpet.sys/clinicas, it returns me 404 error. But http://eguru.idpet.sys/index.php/clinicas, opens the route correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Try `$ a2enmod rewrite` and then restart apache.

Here is the [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) `.htaccess`, have you tried this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! a2enmod was it!